# Why does the line keyboard = new Scanner(keyboard.nextLine()); keep the program from hanging?

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out how to input multiple tokens at one time using the `Scanner` class.  I found some code that works perfectly.  I know that the `Scanner.hasNext` method can block indefinitely.  Why does the line `keyboard = new Scanner(keyboard.nextLine());` in this code keep it from doing this?

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();

    System.out.println("Please enter your full name: ");
    keyboard = new Scanner(keyboard.nextLine());

    while(keyboard.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println("tag ");
        ll.add(keyboard.next());

    }

    System.out.println(ll);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`keyboard` will be a `Scanner` which reads tokens from the first line of input.

When you use the `Scanner(String str)` constructor, the resulting scanner will use `str` as input.

If that's clear to you, you probably just need to understand that the terminal IO is line-buffered. This means that the scanner will have nothing to read until you press <kbd>return</kbd>.